# Functions of polynomial growth on linear algebraic groups

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, lie-groups, algebraic-groups

$\DeclareMathOperator\GL{GL}$Let $G$ be a complex [linear algebraic group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_algebraic_group), i.e. a subgroup in $\GL_n({\mathbb C})$, defined by a system of polynomial equations
$$
p_i(x)=0
$$
(here $p_i$ are polynomials on $\GL_n({\mathbb C})$, and we can think that they are polynomials on the space $L_n({\mathbb C})$ of all matrices of dimension $n\times n$).

This is a complex Lie group, and we can consider holomorphic functions on it. Let us say that a holomorphic function $f:G\to{\mathbb C}$ has *polynomial growth*, if for some $N\in{\mathbb N}$ and $C\ge 0$
$$
|f(x)|\le C\cdot \max\{\|x\|,\|x^{-1}\|\}^N,\qquad x\in G,
$$
where $\|\cdot\|$ is a matrix norm, for example,
$$
\|x\|=\sum_{i,j}|x_{i,j}|.
$$

My intuition suggests me that

> among holomorphic functions on $G$ only polynomials have polynomial growth, i.e. the functions $f:G\to{\mathbb C}$ of the form
> $$
> f(x)=\frac{q(x)}{(\det x)^k},\qquad x\in G,
> $$
> where $q:L_n({\mathbb C})\to{\mathbb C}$ is a polynomial, and $k\in{\mathbb N}=\{0,1,2,...\}$.

Is that true?

I can prove this only in the case when $G=\GL_n({\mathbb C})$, and I have to use the [Riemann extension theorem](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Extension_theorems_(in_analytic_geometry)) for this. Can anybody enlighten me if the same is true for arbitrary linear algebraic groups $G$?